# Routing issue on hosted website using Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am having an issue regarding routing on my live website. Locally the routing works fine but when a user refreshes the page a 404 error is thrown and the same happens when a user clicks on a link that takes them to an external website and they press the back button. I am familiar with angular but this is my first time hosting a website.

Here is my app-routing.module.ts code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'landing', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dragonevolution', component: BodyComponent },
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingPageComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
      scrollOffset: [0, 64] // [x, y]
    })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I'm not sure which part of the routing I am misunderstanding because the:

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'landing', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

should handle any route that is not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Your server likely needs configuration to remap urls if you're hosting an angular application on your own. They have a section about this in the documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

With a few guides on various types.